# Listing Frameworks folder on Mac gives different results due to EWSMac.framework

Tags: macos

I can't understand what is happening. I am using macOS 10.14.6. I am simply trying to find `R.framework` which is inside `Library/Frameworks` folder I get EWSMac.framework (I don't know what is this):

```
MBP:~ me$ cd Library/Frameworks
MBP:Frameworks sergiobacelar$ ls
EWSMac.framework
```

But when I do:

```
MBP:~ me$ cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
MBP:Resources me$ cd ..
MBP:R.framework me$ cd ..
MBP:Frameworks me$ ls
AEProfiling.framework       PROJ.framework
AERegistration.framework    PluginManager.framework
```

I get the usual list of frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` matters

This is the Unix file system and use of relative and absolute paths .

All Unix files and directories are in one space all under the root directory `/`

An absolute path is one beginning with / and is always seen the same.

If the path does not beginning with / it is a relative path and if used it is appened to your current working directory.

So in the first case you are in your home directory which the shell shows as `~`.  The shell expands ~ to the absolute path of your home diurectory which is usually `/Users/me` if your user name is me. You then cd to a directory that adds the parameter you pass to cd to the current directory e.g. you cd to `/Users/me/Library/Frameworks` which contains frameworks just for your user which in this case is EWSMac.

To see this after you cd in both cases enter the command `pwd` to show what directory you are in.